# ¿Debería recuperar una pregunta en la que estaba trabajando?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, eliminación-de-preguntas, pregunta-autorespondida

Estaba escribiendo una respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36421/colocar-un-select-option-dentro-un-div-en-d3-js) y cuando estaba a punto de darle al botón de "Publica tu Respuesta" me apareció un mensaje diciendo que el autor la había borrado y ya no puedo publicar la respuesta.

La pregunta parece válida: es un error concreto, e incluye los datos y el código relevante (aunque el mcve esté en un JSFiddle). No hay razón aparente para que la pregunta se haya borrado, a no ser que OP haya encontrado la solución, pero entonces mejor que borrar la pregunta sería añadir una respuesta.

¿Qué debería hacer en ese caso?

Tengo la opción de recuperar la pregunta, pero nunca la he usado y no sé si éste sería un caso en el que usarla (me parece algo egoísta al no saber la razón por la que OP cerró la pregunta).

¿Es "recuperar" una opción válida en ese caso?

Comment: Puede haber mil motivos por los que haya borrado la pregunta: que haya encontrado la solución, que se haya dado cuenta de que había otro método más fácil y haya desechado utilizar este o incluso que haya desechado por completo esta opción. Realmente creo que el OP debe ser el último usuario en decidir si quiere mantener una pregunta abierta/cerrada puesto que él es el que ha generado la duda. Sé que fastidia, a mí también me ha pasado que borren la pregunta justo al ir a enviar, pero creo que, si el OP ha decidido que ya no quiere tener esa pregunta, es decisión suya mantenerla así.

Comment: @Error404 "_si el OP ha decidido que ya no quiere tener esa pregunta, es decisión suya mantenerla así_", opino parecido y por eso he preguntado... pero (siempre hay un pero), si esa fuera la lógica a seguir, la opción de "recuperar" no existiría porque se respetaría la decisión del OP, pero existe.

Comment: Creo que la opción de recuperar tiene más sentido en caso de que eliminen una pregunta y el OP pida volverla a reabrir (por los motivos X, ya sea porque quiere editarla y formatearla bien o porque ha encontrado una solución a su problema y quiere compartirlo con todos). Realmente es una pena que no sepamos si una pregunta eliminada por el OP es porque "era una chorrada" o porque al final ha desechado esa opción. Creo que todas las preguntas bien formateadas podrían ayudar a alguien en un futuro.

Comment: No sabía que existía la opción de recuperar una pregunta, me ha pasado varias veces lo que dices, preparar una respuesta y que al querer enviarla la han borrado. Si la pregunta es interesante no veo porque no recuperarla aunque quizá el OP no quiere aparecer como autor de la misma, entonces lo que se puede hacer es redactarla de nuevo si puedes visualizarla todavía o recuerdas el enunciado más o menos.

Comment: Si ya tienes la respuesta trabaja. Si consideras que ayuda a mas uno. Entonces hazla como una nueva pregunta y contéstala. ¿Para que recuperar si puedes preguntar tu mismo?

Comment: He creado la pregunta y la he respondido, pero hay motivos por los que sigo pensando que recuperar habría sido una mejor opción (por ejemplo, el código de la pregunta es el mismo que el de la pregunta original, y si el usuario recupera su pregunta, la mía será básicamente un duplicado).

Comment: Leyendo los comentarios, parece que la opción de  recuperar ni siquiera debería existir.

Comment: Se puede recuperar a partir de rep. 2000, por eso nunca había visto esa opción: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools. A mi me parece bien que se puedan recuperar preguntas interesantes, sugerí  redactarla de nuevo por evitar conflictos con el autor, no sé como aparece la autoría al recuperarla pero tampoco me parece muy distinto a que alguien te edite una pregunta o respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que en este caso, y si tienes acceso a la pregunta original (ya sea por caching o porque ya tienes reputación de 10K), lo suyo es formularla tú mismo.

Me explico: si una pregunta te llamó la atención y consideras que es digna de ser respondida, probablemente sea un conocimiento que quieras compartir con la comunidad. Por ello, qué mejor que elegir un redactado de pregunta interesante para encarar la respuesta que ya tenías preparada.